# Factory reset windows OS on dual booted system

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, reset

I have ubuntu installed along side Windows 10. I want to factory reset my windows OS.

Will it affect my Ubuntu OS in anyway ?

What should I take care of before resetting ?

Comment: If BIOS be sure to have good backups and make another backup of just your partition table. Windows conviently forgets to include Linux partitions when it rewrites partition table. Data is still there & you just need to restore partition table. If gpt that issue does not seem to be there. But now Windows adds another recovery partition after its main partition and may overwrite the beginning of the next partition if Linux. That is not recoverable, so be sure to have good backups.

Comment: @PRATAP depending on the way Windows does its factory reset that light ot might not be very dangerous advice (See answer)

Answer (score 0):

**Do not follow the duplicate as Windows Factory reset might wipe your entire disk!**

What you should is it to:

1. Take a screen shot of your current `gparted` disk configuration.
2. Make a full System backup on an external HDD using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) Using Disk to Image.
3. Do the Windows thing *(Off-topic here)*

   - Check in Windows Disk Manager whether that wiped your Ubuntu partitions or not.
   - If it did not, but Ubuntu doesn't boot, skip to step 6
   - If it did wipe the Ubuntu partitions, go to the next step.
4. Boot Ubuntu in "Try" mode
5. Run `gparted` again and resize your partitions manually as noted in step #1
6. Restore your system backup
7. **Optional:** Run [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if Ubuntu doesn't start.